# Line Breaks in Text Mode not Working

Tags: line-breaking, pseudocode

This is a follow up from [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45328/labeling-pseudo-code-with-algorithm-steps#comment92945_45328)

I am writing a large document in LaTeX, part of which is giving me much grief.

Specifically, I have described an algorithm in several numbered steps. I have then given the pseudo code for this algorithm, in which I would like to reference these steps.

Sometimes, multiple lines of the pseudo code refer to one step in the algorithm description. As such, I would like to draw a big right brace (`}`) enclosing those lines, and label it with the step number.

From what I have learned from the LaTeX documentation, I have the following (relevant) snippets of code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.2mm}}
\begin{document}
\title{Single Source Multi-Commodity Network Flow}
\date{December 18, 2011}
\author{Ashwin Panchapakesan \\
        University of Ottawa \\
        Student Number: 6588301 \\
        apanc006@uottawa.ca}
\maketitle

\section{Pseudo-code}
.

function getNeighbor(V,E, paths, dist)

\indent \indent extern A

\indent \indent u $\leftarrow$ NULL

\indent \indent n $\leftarrow$ NULL

\indent \indent while (u = NULL) DO

\[
 \left.
 \text{ 
    us $\leftarrow$ \{ v $\in V | \exists$ t $\in$ T $\cap v, \newline$ \} 
    ($\exists$ e $\in E | v \in$ e, c(e) = $\infty$), \linebreak \linebreak
    $\indent \indent \indent \indent$ routable(u, paths) if $\exists$ u $\in V | (u,v) \in$ E else routable(u, paths) \linebreak
    $\indent \indent \indent \indent$ where (v,u) $\in$ E, w(e) $\leq$ dist \}
    $\indent \indent \indent \indent$ where (v,u) $\in$ E, w(e) $\leq$ dist \}
 }
 \right\rbrace step \ref{getListofNodes}
\]

\indent \indent \indent // step \ref{getListofNodes}

\indent \indent \indent $us \leftarrow \{ v \in V | \exists t \in T \cap v, $

\indent \indent \indent \indent ($\exists e \in E | v \in e, c(e) = \infty$), 

\indent \indent \indent \indent routable(u, paths) if $\exists u \in V | (u,v) \in E else$ routable(u, paths) 

\indent \indent \indent \indent where (v,u) $\in E, w(e) \leq dist \} $

\indent \indent \indent U $\leftarrow$ max$_{\sum_{e \in paths.values} w(e)}$ \{ paths \} // step \ref{setU}

\indent \indent \indent  // step \ref{setU} begins

\indent \indent \indent if (U $\in$ us) then

\indent \indent \indent \indent u $\leftarrow$ U

\indent \indent \indent else

\indent \indent \indent \indent u $\leftarrow$ randomChoice(us)

\indent \indent \indent // step \ref{setU} ends

\indent \indent // step \ref{setN} begins

\indent \indent while (n = NULL) do

\indent \indent \indent ns $\leftarrow \{ v \in V | u \neq v,$ \linebreak
\indent \indent \indent \indent $(\exists e \in E | e=(u,v) \text{ or } e=(v,u), c(e) = \infty),$ \linebreak
\indent \indent \indent \indent $min_{w(e)} {e \in E | e=(u,v) \text{ or } e=(v,u)} \leq dist\}$

\indent \indent n $\leftarrow$ randomChoice(ns)

\indent \indent // step \ref{setN} ends

\indent \indent // step \ref{setR} begins

\indent \indent ress $\leftarrow$ \{$ a_i \in A | t_i \in n$ \}

\indent \indent r $\leftarrow$ randomChoice(ress)

\indent \indent // step \ref{setR} ends

\indent \indent r $\leftarrow a_i$ for some $a_i \in A$


\indent \indent // step \ref{changeTerminal} begins

\indent \indent $t_i \leftarrow n$

\indent \indent $\forall e \in $ paths[r] do

\indent \indent \indent f(e) $\leftarrow$ f(e) - 1

\indent \indent // step \ref{changeTerminal} ends

\indent \indent // step \ref{changePath} beings \linebreak
\indent \indent p = min$_{\sum_{path}w(e)}$ \{ path $|$ path = paths[r], $\exists a_i \in A | r = a_i, t_i \in n$, \linebreak
\indent \indent \indent $\forall e \in paths[r] c(e)-f(e)>0$ \}

\indent \indent $\forall e \in p$ do

\indent \indent \indent \indent f(e) $\leftarrow$ f(e) + 1

\indent \indent paths[r] $\leftarrow$ paths[r] + min$_{w(e)}$ \{$ e \in E |e=(u,n) or e=(n,u) $ \}

\indent \indent // step \ref{changePath} ends

\end{document}
```

My problem is that the `\newline`s and `\linebreak`s are not displayed in the output document - they do not produce a line break. Instead all the intended multiple lines are displayed on one line and are truncated at the page margins.

Also, I know that between `\text{` and `}` is the text environment, just like between `$` and `$` is the math environment. Could anyone please clarify the name of the environment within `\[` and `\]`?

I'd appreciate any help on how I can fix this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\newline` and `\linebreak` have no effect inside `\text`. You should consider the `tabbing` environment. Here's the first part of your pseudo-code, that can be completed in the same way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.2mm}}
\begin{document}
\title{Single Source Multi-Commodity Network Flow}
\date{December 18, 2011}
\author{Ashwin Panchapakesan \\
        University of Ottawa \\
        Student Number: 6588301 \\
        apanc006@uottawa.ca}
\newcommand{\vv}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\maketitle

\section{Pseudo-code}

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{20pt}\=\hspace*{20pt}\=\hspace*{20pt}\=\kill
function $\vv{getNeighbor}(V, E, \vv{paths}, \vv{dist})$ \\
\> extern $A$ \\
\> $u\leftarrow \mathrm{NULL}$ \\
\> $n$ $\leftarrow \mathrm{NULL}$ \\
\> while ($u = \mathrm{NULL}$) DO \\
$\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{20pt}\=\hspace*{20pt}\=\hspace*{20pt}\=\kill
\>\> $\vv{us}\leftarrow \{ v \in V \mid \exists t \in T \cap v$ \\
\>\>\> ($\exists e\in E \mid v \in e, c(e) = \infty$), \\
\>\>\> $\vv{routable}(u, \vv{paths})$ if $\exists u \in V \mid (u,v) \in E$ else $\vv{routable}(u,\vv{paths}$) \\
\>\>\> where $(v,u) \in E$, $w(e) \leq \vv{dist}$ \\
\>\>\> where $(v,u) \in E$, $w(e) \leq \vv{dist}\}$
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
\right\rbrace\text{step \ref{getListofNodes}}$ \\
\>\> // step \ref{getListofNodes} \\

\>\> $\vv{us}\leftarrow \{ v \in V \mid \exists t \in T \cap v,$ \\
\>\>\> ($\exists e \in E \mid v \in e, c(e) = \infty$), \\
\>\>\> $\vv{routable}(u, \vv{paths})$ if $\exists u \in V \mid (u,v) \in E$ else $\vv{routable}(u,\vv{paths})$ \\
\>\>\> where $(v,u)\in E$, $w(e) \leq dist \}$\\
\>\> $U\leftarrow\max_{\sum_{e \in \vv{paths.values}} w(e)} \{ \vv{paths} \}$ // step \ref{setU} \\
\>\> // step \ref{setU} begins \\
\>\> if ($U \in \vv{us}$) then \\
\>\>\> $u\leftarrow U$ \\
\>\> else \\
\>\>\> $u\leftarrow \vv{randomChoice}(\vv{us})$ \\
\>\> // step \ref{setU} ends \\

[...]

\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The wide brace is a bit tricky: it uses a nested `tabbing` environment in a `minipage`, exploiting the fact that a `minipage` that contains only a `tabbing` is as wide as necessary.

Comment: I've always been a fan of the `tabbing` environment.